# I am trying to understand forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

So I have a physics final soon, and I have been doing okay but I did fail my forces test because I honestly don't understand the concept too well. For example, I am redoing all of my practice tests and I can't even do this problem, can someone explain this to me:

> Two blocks rest on a horizontal friction less surface as shown to the right. The surface between the top and bottom blocks ii roughened so that there is no slipping between the two blocks. A 30N force is applied to the bottom block as shown in the figure. (A 5kg block on a 10kg block, there is a 30N force on the bottom 10kg block).

How do I do this? This seems like a really simple forces problem and since I really blurred past forces I really don't understand it. If it is on a friction less surface then shouldn't the net force of both blocks be 30N because that is what is being applied?

Comment: your question is missing figure

Comment: A 5kg block on a 10kg block, there is a 30N force on the bottom 10kg block

Comment: What is the question in this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are right net force on both the block would be $30\,\rm N$. Then, the acceleration of the combination would be

$$a = \frac{30\,\rm N}{10\, \rm kg + 5\, kg} = 2\,\rm m/s^2$$

As there is no slippage between the blocks, force acting on $10\,\rm kg$ block would be

$$F = 10\,\rm kg \cdot 2\, m/s^2 = 20\, N$$

Similarly, force acting on $5\,\rm kg$ block would be

$$F = 5\,\rm kg \cdot 2\, m/s^2 = 10\, N$$

Comment: Hi Vikash Kumar. The equations become much easier to read, search and edit when [mathjax](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5610/75633) is used. Note that andselisk already fixed that for you here, but it'd be great if you could use it yourself in your next posts.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not quite. If there were a $30\,\rm N$ force on the $5\,\rm kg$ block, it would accelerate at $6\,\rm m/s^2$, which is faster than the $10\,\rm kg$ block's acceleration and so it would slip off.

Here's how to do it. $30\,\rm N$ acts on the entire $15\,\rm kg$ system, which produces a $2\,\rm m/s^2$ acceleration. Since there is no slippage between the $5\,\rm kg$ block and the $10\,\rm kg$ block, this is also the acceleration experienced by the $5\,\rm kg$ block. From there you can calculate that the force acting on the $5\,\rm kg$ block is $10\,\rm N$, and the source of this force is the friction between the two blocks.

As for the $10\,\rm kg$ block, the net force acting on it is $20\,\rm N$ (as can be calculated from $F = ma$ and the acceleration). There's a $30\,\rm N$ force applied on it, and there's a $10\,\rm N$ force from the friction in the opposite direction, which cancels and yields $20\,\rm N$.

Comment: Hi. The equations become much easier to read, search and edit when mathjax is used. Note that andselisk already fixed that for you here, but it'd be great if you could use it yourself in your next posts.

Comment: With complex equations I'd always use mathtype, didn't consider these complex ...

Comment: You're right, here it was only an aesthetics issue.

Answer (score 0):

> If it is on a friction less surface then shouldn't the net force of both blocks be 30N because that is what is being applied?

Yes. You can consider anything as your system or object. If you consider both blocks as one object/system, then this object/system feels three forces, namely the (total) weight, the normal force and the push from the side. The weight and normal force cancel out so the net force on this object/system is 30 N.

That net force then causes an acceleration according to Newton's 2nd law. The whole object/system moves with this acceleration, meaning that each block does.

So far this is quite easy. Depending on what you need to find. But if you need to find for example the static friction between them which holds them together, then you must decide on another system. It won't be useful to consider both blocks as one object, since the static friction then will be an internal force. And internal forces cancel out an disappear in Newton's 2nd law.

So in that case, decide on another system. For example consider the bottom block alone. What forces act on it?

- It's own weight as well as
- a push from the top one due to that one's weight,
- the normal force and then
- the external push from the side AND
- the static friction that grabs on to the top block and pulls it along.

You will have to draw a small force diagram and think about each of their directions. This is usually where most mistakes are made, especially regarding frictions.

When this diagram is done you have a perfect overview. And then Newton's laws can solve anything you need.

If you can be more specific in the exact thing this question asks you to find, then we can be more detailed. But in any case, what I have described here is the bulletproof method:

1. Decide what your system is.
2. Draw force diagram strictly for that system only.
3. Use Newton's laws to find whatever you need.

Always.